# Search running spatially with PHP, MYSQL, GROUP_CONCAT and JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, search, join, group-concat

I made some changes in the code and now it's working. But there is a new problem.
In the database, I have registered 3 Company Cods: G-1001, G-1002 and G-1004.

If I type "g", "g-", or for instance "g-100" and click search, it returns me all the results correctly. But if I type just "g-1001" or even "01", "001", it returns no results.

Why it's not working when I search the last characters of the registered code?

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'send'){
    $codsearch = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?()!-]#i', '', $_POST['searchcompanycod']);

    $getresultsquery = mysql_query('SELECT p.*, a.idProduct, a.idVehic, a.year, v.nameVehic, GROUP_CONCAT(a.year SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(a.idVehic SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(v.nameVehic SEPARATOR "<br>")
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN application a ON p.idProduct = a.idProduct
    INNER JOIN vehic v ON a.idVehic = v.idVehic
    WHERE codCompany LIKE "%'.$codsearch.'%"
    GROUP BY p.codCompany') or die(mysql_error());

    $resultsrow = mysql_num_rows($getresultsquery);
    if($resultsrow > 1){
        echo "$codsearch";
        echo "<table class='table table-bordered' border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Company Code</th><th>Original Code</th><th>Descr.</th><th>idProduct</th><th>idVehic</th><th>Vehic Name</th><th>Year</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($getresultsline = mysql_fetch_array($getresultsquery)) {
            echo "<tr>";  
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['codCompany'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['codOriginal'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['typeDesc'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['idProduct'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['GROUP_CONCAT(a.idVehic SEPARATOR "<br>")'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['GROUP_CONCAT(v.nameVehic SEPARATOR "<br>")'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $getresultsline['GROUP_CONCAT(a.year SEPARATOR "<br>")'] . "</td>";  
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }   else{
            echo "No results";}
}
?>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?
My testing page is: http://flyingmail.com.br/test/produtos.php (only Company Code filter working)

Comment: You spelled `veicle` wrong. Should be `vehicle`. (Just nitpicking). Try and use [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) where possible to avoid things like `$getresultsline['GROUP_CONCAT(table2.date SEPARATOR "<br>")']`.

Comment: Can you paste the raw `img tables` so that I can easily convert it to a schema for sqlfiddle.

Comment: Your quotes are wrong/mismatched - `'SELECT ...[your query]... LIKE '%".$codsearch."%''`. Since you start with a single quote `'`, you can concatenate with double qoutes `"`. It should be `...LIKE "%'.$codsearch.'%"'`

Comment: You're doing strange things with MySQL's horrible nonstandard extension to GROUP BY.  Read this.  If you misuse GROUP BY like this, your query will be like the talking burro. It's not astounding that it works badly, it's astounding it works at all.

Comment: @Sean Post that as an answer.

Comment: I changed the quotes in this piece of code: "%'.$codsearch.'%" but now I'm having another strange issue.

Comment: I think my problem is the PHP, because when I run the SQL in PHP MyAdmin replacing "%'.$codsearch.'%" by "G-1001" it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Hahaha terrible... it could never be `if($resultsrow > 1){` because if I search for something specific, it will return only 1 row. So, it must be `if($resultsrow >= 1){`

LOL

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting on your SQL should show you the main issue.

Change

```
'SELECT table1.*, table2.productID, table2.veicleID, table2.date, table3.veicleNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.date SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.veicleNAME SEPARATOR "<br>")
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.productID = table2.productID
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.veicleID = table3.veicleID
    GROUP BY productID
    HAVING productID LIKE '%".$codsearch."%''
```

to

```
"SELECT table1.*, table2.productID, table2.veicleID, table2.date, table3.veicleNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.date SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.veicleNAME SEPARATOR "<br>")
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.productID = table2.productID
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.veicleID = table3.veicleID
    GROUP BY productID
    HAVING productID LIKE '%".$codsearch."%'"
```

(note that I changed the first and last single quote to a double quote)

Comment: I changed the quotes in this piece of code: "%'.$codsearch.'%" but now I'm having another strange issue.